# Place PlotMarkers in front of error bars with ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm making an `ErrorListPlot` where the error bars are a different color then the markers and it works, however, the error bars are drawn in front of the markers and it looks funny. See the following example

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

data = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];

ErrorListPlot[
 data,
 PlotRange -> All,
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2],
 PlotStyle -> RGBColor[159/255, 158/255, 204/255],
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Opacity[1], Darker@Blue, Disk[]}, 0.01 5}}
 ]
```

[image]

See how the error bars are drawn over the markers. I want them to be behind. I tried to use `Epilog` to redraw the markers but they don't have a uniform aspect ratio.

`Epilog -> ({Opacity[1], Darker@Blue, Disk[#, 0.025]} & /@ data[[All, 1]])`

[image]

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, I forgot that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1

A little improvement of Your approach would be using `Point` instead of `Disk`:

```
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Orange,  PlotMarkers -> None,
              Epilog -> ({Darker@Blue, PointSize@.03, Point@data[[All, 1]]})],
              BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2]]
```

[image]

### 2

Not so obvious and I'm not sure if universal for `ErrorListPlot` but:

```
plot = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2],   
                 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Opacity[1], Darker@Blue, Disk[]}, 0.01 5}},
                 PlotStyle -> Orange];

plot// Replace[#, k_List :> Reverse@k, {6}] &
```

[image]

less handy but more safe(?):

```
plot /. GraphicsComplex[x_, y_, z___] :> 
        GraphicsComplex[x, Replace[y, k_List :> Reverse@k, {3}], z]
```

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious  ...

```
data = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
                         BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], 
                         PlotStyle -> RGBColor[159/255, 158/255, 204/255], 
                         PlotMarkers -> None], 
     ListPlot[data[[All, 1]], 
                         PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, in the end I accepted Kuba's answer since his/hers didn't require plotting twice, although the overhead of yours wasn't really relevant.

Comment: @s0rce *his :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also post-process `ErrorListPlot` output to move the `Inset`s after the `Line`s:

```
ClearAll[markersInFront]
markersInFront = # /. {i_Inset, x__} :> {x, i} &;
```

Examples:

```
elplt = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
   BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2],  ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[159/255, 158/255, 204/255], 
   PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Opacity[1], Darker@Blue, Disk[]},  0.01 5}}];

Row[{elplt, markersInFront @ elplt}]
```

[image]

Using `PlotMarkers -> {Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 30]}` in `elplt` above, we get
[image]

**Notes:**  Both examples above work fine in Version 9.2. As noted by @Alexey Popkov in a comment:

1. In version 11.2, we need to use
   `PlotMarkers->{{Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"],Boxed->Fa‌​lse,ImageSize->30],.‌​1}}`.
2. In version 10.2+, we need to use `Show[elplt, PlotRange -> All]` and `Show[markersInFront @ elplt,  PlotRange -> All]` to avoid cropping of some error bars (See also [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120967/280) on this issue.)

Comment: (+1) For some reason `PlotMarkers -> {Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"], Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 30]}` doesn't work with version 11.2.0. But the following form works: `PlotMarkers->{{Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"],Boxed->False,ImageSize->30],.1}}`. Also in version 11.2.0 `PlotRange -> All` doesn't include all the error bars, looks like a bug...

Comment: The bug is already reported: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120967/280