# ErrorListPlot - Problem with PlotRange

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

Consider the following example:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

x=Table[n,{n,1,100}];

SeedRandom[314];
y=RandomReal[{9,10},100];
yErr=RandomReal[{0,1},100];

yWithErrors=Transpose[{Transpose[{x,y}],ErrorBar/@yErr}];

ErrorListPlot[yWithErrors, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Transpose[{x, y}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

Independently if I use `PlotRange -> All`, `PlotRange -> Total` or `PlotRange -> Automatic` the output is:

[image]

As you see the error bars are not completely visible.

Is the only solution to see the error bars to set the `PlotRange` manually?

```
ErrorListPlot[yWithErrors, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Transpose[{x, y}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {8, 11}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: seems like a version 10 issue; it doesn't arise [in v9](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LAWaB.png)

Comment: I am running 10.4.1 (Win 64bit Pro).

Comment: This is a bug.  `ErrorListPlot` is no longer considering the error bars when calculating the plot range.  You get the exact same plot range regardless of how large the errors are.

Comment: I reported this as a bug.  A simpler example that shows the issue would be `ErrorListPlot[{.1 #, .8} & /@ Range[10], PlotRange -> All]`, which also shows the utility of kglr's workaround.

Comment: The same problem with version 11 ... Three weeks ago I informed the technical support and they reproduced the problem with version 10.4.1, but that's it ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In version 9, `PlotRange -> All` in `ErrorListPlot` works as expected:

```
ErrorListPlot[yWithErrors, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Transpose[{x, y}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, PlotLabel -> Style[$Version, 20]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In versions 10+,

```
elp=ErrorListPlot[yWithErrors, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Transpose[{x, y}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, PlotLabel->Style[$Version, 20]]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**A work-around:** Wrap the output of `ErrorListPlot` with `Show` using the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Show[elp, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]