# How to force ListPlot show origin (0,0)?

Tags: plotting

I've used `AxesOrigin->{0,0}` in Mathematica until version 9 to get origin $(0,0)$ into the plot. So the following code gave the following output:

```
ListPlot[Table[{3, 3.5}, {x, 1, 10}]//Transpose, Joined->True,
         PlotRange->All, AxesOrigin->{0, 0}]
```

[image: Output from Mathematica 9]

But since Mathematica 10 I instead get the following result:

[image: Output from Mathematica 10-11]

So apparently, `AxesOrigin->{0,0}` no longer forces inclusion of the origin in the plot. How to include the origin in the plot in Mathematica 10 and 11?

Comment: @ciao only works if you know that the functions are only positive for given domain.

Comment: Related: [(87808)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87808/121), [(120967)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120967/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd consider this to be a bug for the option settings `PlotRange -> All` and `PlotRange -> Full`. Or is it just an undocumented change in behavior? In that case it might be added to [your very helpful list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56729/18476).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like using the workaround described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120970/5208) works in my case:

```
Show[#,PlotRange->All]&@
ListPlot[Table[{3, 3.5}, {x, 1, 10}]//Transpose, Joined->True,
     PlotRange->All, AxesOrigin->{0, 0}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
plot = ListPlot[Table[-{3, 3.5}, {x, 1, 10}] // Transpose, 
   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0.01, 0.01}];
```

this should be general enough for `PlotRange->All`:

```
Graphics[
   {#, Opacity[0], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
   PlotRange -> All, ##2
] & @@ plot
```

[image]

Comment: I did think of this hack, but it looks more like a workaround. Is there no way to direct `ListPlot` itself to do this?

Comment: @Ruslan maybe there is but I don't know :)

Answer (score 3):

This change in behavior can be remedied to fit your needs by using a different `PlotRange` specification:

```
PlotRange -> {0, All}
```

Comment: But what if it's inside `Manipulate`, and the plot can go negative sometimes? I'd rather like something like `PlotRange->{Min[0,dataMin],Max[0,dataMax]}`, without need to explicitly find minimum and maximum in the plot data.